# How can I duplicate a line that contains a specific word and a number of consecutive lines e.g.: using awk or sed?

Tags: awk, sed

I'm trying to duplicate and manipulate specific lines of a file, starting out with this example.yaml:

```
game:
  name: test
  ability: 1
  name: other
  ability: 2
```

I want to duplicate the lines `name: test` and `ability: 1`, but nothing else.
I don't want to use line numbers to select the write lines, as the sizes and contents vary.

the result should be:

```
game: 
  name: test
  ability: 1
  name: test
  ability: 1
  name: other 
  ability: 2
```

I managed to solve it with:

```
awk '
/name: test/ {f=1}
/name: other/{
  f=0;
  for(i=1;i<=c;i++) print a[i]
}
f{ print; a[++c]=$0 }
!f{ print}
' example.yaml
```

The problem is that the yaml file varies and that sometimes `name: test ability: 1` is the end of the file, or sometimes it is followed by something else than `name: other`.

An ideal solution should work for whichever lines follow the pattern I want to duplicate:

```
game: 
  name: test
  ability: 1
```

should be:

```
game: 
  name: test
  ability: 1
  name: test
  ability: 1
```

How can I create a more generic solution that does not use the pattern following the one I'm trying to duplicate?

Thanks

Comment: You saying `want to duplicate the lines name:test and ability: play, but nothing else` but your expected output doesn't have `ability: play` line in it? Could you please clarify more on it in your question.

Comment: Use a programming language with a yaml library, like Python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sed it's straightforward:

```
sed '/name: test/{N;p;}' filename
```

Roughly translated, this says "if the line contains `name: test`, then read in the next line as well, then print them out an extra time".

Comment: Thanks a lot! This one seems to be the easiest one to understand and works well.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/\<name: test$/{/\<ability: 1$/p}' file
```

If a line ends `name: test` and the next ends `ability: 1`, duplicate those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Awk alternative:

```
awk '/name: test/ { line=$0 } /ability/ && line!="" { $0=$0"\n"line"\n"$0;line=""}1' file
```

If the line "name: test" is found, set the variable line equal to the read line ($0), then when we find the line ability and line not equal to "" (name is test) set the read line $0 equal to the existing line then a carriage return, the line variable (name:test) and then the existing line again. Reset the line variable to blank. Use short hand 1 to print the line.